# ASP.NET controller always returning the same result

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am building a very simple web API. It is supposed to return the array of teachers when called by ~/api/teachers and a single teacher when called by a property, like phone number in this example ~/api/teacher/123. The first one works fine, but the second just returns the same as the first, and I cannot use that. Here is my controller

```
public class TeachersController : ApiController
{
    Teacher[] teachers = new Teacher[]
    {
        new Teacher{FullName="Bob Jones", Email="bjones@hs.org",Phone="123",School="HighSchool"},
        new Teacher{FullName="Laura Adams", Email="Lara@ms.org",Phone="223",School="MiddleSchool"},
        new Teacher{FullName="Rick Douglas", Email="Rick@es.org",Phone="333",School="Elementary"}
    };

    public IHttpActionResult GetTeacher(string phone)
    {
        var teacher = teachers.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Phone == phone);
        if (teacher == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(teacher);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Teacher> GetAllTeachers()
    {
        return teachers;
    }


}
```

I am using the default routes, which appear to support my idea of how it should work.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I have tried changing the routes to some things found here, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you put on the first line of getTeacher, is the phone string null?

Comment: I would try changing phone to id to match the route's signature.. because at the moment it accepts a controller and an ID, but your method is a controller and a phone.. maybe the problem is there

Comment: My thought is that the issue could be that the phone is just an `int` just to see, try changing one of the phonenumbers to "abc" and see if you can query it on that. (I'm not an expert by any means, just a shot in the dark)

Comment: The parameter that was sent to the server is 'id' instead of 'phone'. you need (1) either change the request to ~/api/teacher?phone=123 or (2) change the method to getTeacher(string id)

Comment: Changing (string phone) to (string id) worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method prototype to

> public IHttpActionResult GetTeacher(string id)

**or**

Add a route config with the template

> "api/{controller}/{phone}"

Your route is defined for a parameter named `id` which must match the name of your parameter. You can also just change the route to expect `phone` instead of `id`

Comment: I had missed the connection there. I thought the id in the routing config was just a local variable declared there, and not linked to the controller methods. This makes sense now.